# Add XY Column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry

Following on from a previous question of mine, where I was given coords in degree-mins, I have successfully converted them to decimal degrees, thanks for the help.

I have created a CSV file from the stated coordinates, and then created a shapefile. The CRS was EPSG:4326 (WGS84).

The remainder of my mapping is displayed in TM65/Irish Grid (EPSG:29902). With the on the fly projections activated, everything is displayed properly. I need to provide this to a 3rd party.

How do I use QGIS to add a geometry colunm using the Current CRS? Using either QGIS 1.8 or 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "current" CRS should be TM65/Irish Grid, you have to save the shapefile under another name and that CRS, and add that to the canvas.
Then you can add x and y coordinates to the attribute table using the field calculator.

Alternatively, you can select the **project** CRS using `Vector -> Geometry tools -> Export geometry columns`. There is no direct way to add "on-the-fly"-coordinates to the shapefile using field calculator or mmqgis plugin.